# Symfony2 change Form data_class from events

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have 3 entities with discriminator,

`Product`, `ProductOne` and `ProductTwo`

they have just one form `ProductType` because they share most of their properties, `data_class` is assigned to `Appbundle\Entity\Product` but I want to change on `POST_SUBMIT` the entity associated, because depending on one property, entity can be `ProductOne` or `ProductTwo`.

I can't extend form types, and I don't want to create n form types, just one with events, I don't think it's even possible, but I would like to.

I know I can change properties etc but not the `FormData` associated, in this case as I've said it's an instance of `Product` and it must be `ProductOne` or `ProductTwo`

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function(FormEvent $event) {
    $data = $event->getData(); // This form is Product
    $form = $event->getForm();

    if(strpos(strtolower($data->getCategory()->getName()), 'foo')) {
        // Here it must be ProductOne
    } elseif(strpos(strtolower($data->getCategory()->getName()), 'bar')) {
        // Here it must be ProductTwo
    } else {
        // ...
    }
});
```